# Why is setting some variabes such as CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH in cmake toolchain not effective?

Tags: cmake

Demo toolchain file named toolchain.cmake:

```
set(CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH TRUE)
```

Demo CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(test)

message("CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH: ${CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH}")
```

By executing the following command with CMake 3.16.5 I got `CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH: NO` but I expect to see `CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH: TRUE`

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=toolchain.cmake .
```

After some experimenting, I found that some variables have the same behavior as CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH, such as CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE. For such variables, I have to use `set(<var> <value> CACHE <type> <docstring>)` in the toolchain to make them effective. Other variables, such as CMAKE_BULID_TYPE, just work with `set(<var> <value>)`.

What makes the difference? What variables require `set(CACHE)` and why?

I suspect it has something to do with [CMP0126](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0126.html) but I'm not sure.

Comment: A toolchain file is executed during the first `project()` call and should describe the target platform and/or compilers which should be used. After executing a toolchain file CMake knows the platform and compilers, so it could set many variables which depends on the platform and compilers. This is usually performed in *platform scripts*. E.g. a Linux platform script could set `CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH` as it knows that Linux supports RPATH.

Comment: Platform scripts rarely explicitly check whether a variable is already set. Instead, they  could just set a CACHE variable: Such setting won't redefine a CACHE variable if it is already set. "What variables require set(CACHE) and why?" - Every variable has its own specific. Unfortunately, CMake documentation rarely describe this aspects. Note, that it is somehow unexpected that a toolchain file could set `CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH` variable: It is project itself who should specify its RPATH policies. Similarly, `CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE` is not expected be set in the toolchain file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your reply! Maybe turn it into an answer. I agree that the project itself should set CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH but sadly we have to control the behavior of cmake projects auto-generated by 3rd-party tools with toolchain files (not a great design, I know). "Every variable has its own specific" -- guess we have to test each used variable's behavior then.  I also found [this Android example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/android-cmake/+/refs/heads/upstream-master/android.toolchain.cmake) of setting RPATH in the toolchain file though.

Comment: Confirmed that the behavior is affected by CMP0126: with a newer version of CMake (>3.21) and setting CMP0126 policy to NEW before project(), the value set with `set(<var> <value>)` in the toolchain is effective in the CMakeLists.txt. (Just recording the experiment result, not that I am going to solve the problem by setting the policy.)